# Can I use bash variables when adding policies to bucket with AWS CLI?

Tags: bash, aws-cli

I'm using the AWS CLI to create and upload policies to a number of buckets - example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
NAME="test_client"
aws s3 create-bucket --bucket ${NAME}_source_bucket
```

Great. All good so far. Next, I'd like to run the following:

```
ARN="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
put-bucket-policy --bucket ${NAME}_source_bucket --policy source_bucket_policy.json
```

Where my bucket policy is to the effect of:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${ARN}:role/${NAME}_source_role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${NAME}_source_bucket"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${ARN}:role/${NAME}_source_role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${NAME}_source_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are writing this from a script, you could use a [heredoc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

If you're running this repeatedly from the command line, you could also create a template JSON.

**Heredoc**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
NAME="test_client"
aws s3 create-bucket --bucket ${NAME}_source_bucket
ARN="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
put-bucket-policy --bucket ${NAME}_source_bucket --policy << EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${ARN}:role/${NAME}_source_role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${NAME}_source_bucket"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${ARN}:role/${NAME}_source_role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${NAME}_source_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
```

**Template**

```sh
# create the template, only need to do this once
cat << EOF > mytemplate.json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<ARN>:role/<NAME>_source_role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<NAME>_source_bucket"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<ARN>:role/<NAME>_source_role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<NAME>_source_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
EOF

# overwrite the template with your values
NAME="test_client"
ARN="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
sed -e "s/<ARN>/${ARN}/g" -e "s/<NAME>/${NAME}/g" mytemplate.json > source_bucket_policy.json

# run aws commands
aws s3 create-bucket --bucket ${NAME}_source_bucket
put-bucket-policy --bucket ${NAME}_source_bucket --policy source_bucket_policy.json
```